# Tags with at least 10 questions that need usage guidance

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I went through and looked for tags with no usage guidance/blank wiki excerpts having at least 10 questions on the site. Here they are:

- <del>[bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodline) 26 questions</del>
- <del>[immediate-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-actions) 23 questions</del>
- <del>[move-action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/move-action) 23 questions</del>
- [aegis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aegis) 19 questions
- <del>[inquisitor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inquisitor) 16 questions</del>
- [channel-energy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/channel-energy) 10 questions

If you volunteer to fix one or more of these, just leave an answer documenting your changes.

Comment: [the Bloodline one warrants separate action](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11681/problematic-tag-bloodline/11682#11682) - there is a VtM question among the Sorcerer ones.

Comment: [Aegis](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11689/which-questions-with-aegis-do-lack-the-aegis-tag) seems to have a large number of "missing" questions under its fold, that might help to dish out a good tag.

Answer (score 3):

I've added usage guidance for the following tags in that list:

[bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodline)

> For questions related to special bloodlines (such as vampiric, draconic, etc) and gameplay or narrative features related to them.

[inquisitor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inquisitor)

> For questions about the Inquisitor, a Pathfinder 1e divine class.

(All 16 questions in this tag are also Pathfinder 1e questions; we can update if/when there's another kind of Inquisitor people begin asking about)

[move-action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/move-action)

> for questions about specifics of using move actions, in games where that's a component of the action economy.

[immediate-actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-actions)

> In the D&D and Pathfinder family of games, the Immediate Action is an action that takes place nearly-instantaneously. In the context of D&D 4e, this is in reference to immediate interrupts and reactions, which are triggered actions.

In D&D 4e, the use of immediate actions is exclusively in the form of reactive, triggered moves. For example, opportunity attacks are an immediate interrupt; so is timely dodge. I don't know if that's also the case in D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder 1e, but if so this description could be massively simplified.

Comment: Note that there are already separate tags for [immediate-interrupt] and [immediate-reaction]; that said, [there are some D&D 4e questions that use the \[immediate-actions\] tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e+immediate-actions).

Comment: "reactive, triggered moves" perfectly describes Pathfinder's concept, though AoO is a different beast there. Still, I think the hoped for simplification is perfectly appropriate, as long as it doesn't explicitely mention attacks of opportunity.

Comment: D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder don’t _always_ have immediate actions necessarily be triggered; some immediate actions are simply immediate actions because that lets you do them whenever you like. However, those are a small, small minority (<10% I’d guess), so I think the simplification is still fine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I've simplified the tag summary a bit further then, viewable on the tag page.